# not showing HttpResponse in django python

Tags: django, django-views

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sample'
]
```

sample/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

mainapp/ urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from sample import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/',views.hello),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

but when I run python manage.py runserver it is not showing the 8000/hello/ page

Comment: Exactly what does it show in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I've recreate your app in a new django project and it works fine

I share the code and directory structure of the app, I hope this helps you.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'sample'
 ]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from sample import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/',views.hello),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run **`python manage.py runserver`** inside the folder where manage.py file is present.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the page `8000/hello` but (default) port 8000, page "hello".

> Try to run: `127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`